# How to make my extension html background full transparent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have this white small box and i want to make him transparent before starting adding my html code, i searched already how to do that but i didnt find any type of example.

**Image:**

[image]

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-    scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  list-style:none;
  border:0
}

html {
  background: transparent;
}
```

[EDIT]

[image]

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* border-radius: 16px; */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(11.6px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(11.6px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

**Html**

```
<!-- I added this div -->
<div>
    TESTE
</div>
```

Comment: This is not possible with the standard popup. You can add your UI as an element to the web page instead.

Comment: That isnt the purpose of my extension i want a popup who does not have "connection" with the actual opened tab. So if this is not possible i will try to create other style :(

Answer (score -2):

Please improve your question. If you want to make an element transparent with CSS, the easiest way is to add numbers from `0-9` to the end of the color value to get the transparency level you want, for example, white is `#fff`, to make it transparent experiment with `#ffffff0`, `#ffffff1`, `#ffffff2`, to `9`.

Comment: I added my code but i dont know how to be more specific, i tried add html { background-color: #ffffff0} as you said, but the background keeps white.

Comment: Now I see the problem,  try this html, body { background: transparent} the white color you are seeing is from the body element

Comment: So include body in your second rule

Comment: no effect yet, the white behind didnt changed, i will edit my question with the actual state, soo you can see better what i tried.

Comment: As probably u already know im using manifest.json to control this html, probably i have to make the change on there instead of the css, but i dont know where

Comment: This is simple to achieve

Comment: change <div> TESTE </div> to <div style="background: none">TESTE</div> and see

Comment: may be your stylesheet is not properly linked to the page

Comment: Nope, my stylesheet is linked in the correct way, and the style inline didnt work either lol, this cant be that difficult to change holy moly